# helm - error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 29: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Defined labels in temp with top of the same deployment.yml file-

```
{{- define "chart.labels" }} 
  version: v1.0
  method: http
  internet: enabled
{{- end }}
```

I have deployment.yml file in template folder-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-deployment
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: app1
    type: microservice1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
      type: microservice1
  strategy:
    type: {{ .Values.global.strategytype }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
        type: microservice1
        {{- template "chart.labels" }}
```

The Two ways - one from the keyword *template* (last line of the below code)

And second one from the *include* keyword I am trying to call the template.

```
{{include "chart.labels" . | indent 8 }}
```

- I am getting **error** ( when I am using keyword *template* to call
  the template).

> Error: YAML parse error on chart/templates/deployment.yml: error
> converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected key
> helm.go:81: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did
> not find expected key YAML parse error on
> chart/templates/deployment.yml
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/action.go:165 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).Run
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:247

- Getting another **error** (when I use *Include* keyword to call the
  template)

> Error: YAML parse error on chart/templates/deployment.yml: error
> converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 29: mapping values are not allowed
> in this context helm.go:81: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON:
> yaml: line 29: mapping values are not allowed in this context YAML
> parse error on chart/templates/deployment.yml
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/action.go:165 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).Run
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:247 main.runInstall

What am I missing here ?

Comment: `template  --debug` to see rendered files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow sane indentation. You have:

```
{{- define "chart.labels" }} 
  version: v1.0
  method: http
  internet: enabled
{{- end }}
```

Note there is no double space in chart.labels definition below.

The below works:

```
{{- define "chart.labels" }} 
version: v1.0
method: http
internet: enabled
{{- end }}

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
{{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
{{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "test.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
    {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      labels:
      {{- include "test.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
      {{include "chart.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
```

Edit: Or only change the nindent to match chart.labels in the template meta as below:

```
{{include "chart.labels" . | nindent 6 }}
```

Comment: It was indent issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if some tool has introduced non-breaking space characters into your indents where you think you have spaces. I pasted them into a PyCharm scratch file to see them as [NBSP].